# .asoundrc to merge multiple streams to a single stream, merging two loopback snd-aloop (virtual sound cards)

Tags: audio, alsa

We would like to merge two alsa loopbacks using the .asoundrc mulit pcm, we've followed the [ALSA project - the C library reference](https://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm_plugins.html)

The alsa loopback entities are created using:

> sudo modprobe snd-aloop enable=1,1 index=10,11

The .asoundrc is:

> pcm.quad {
> type multi
>
> ```
> slaves.a.pcm "hw:10,0"
> slaves.a.channels 16
> slaves.b.pcm "hw:11,0"
> slaves.b.channels 16
>
> bindings.0.slave a
> bindings.0.channel 0
> bindings.1.slave a
> bindings.1.channel 1
> bindings.2.slave a
> bindings.2.channel 2
> bindings.3.slave a
> bindings.3.channel 3
> ...
> bindings.14.channel 14
> bindings.15.slave a
> bindings.15.channel 15
>
> bindings.16.slave b
> bindings.16.channel 0
> ...
> bindings.31.slave b
> bindings.31.channel 15
>
> hint.description "Composite multi stream" }
> ```
>
> ctl.quad {
> type hw
> card 0 }

When the following record command is issued:

> arecord -Dquad -f S24_LE -d 15 recorded.wav

the output is:

> Recording WAVE 'recorded.wav' : Signed 24 bit Little Endian, Rate 8000
> Hz, Mono arecord: set_params:1339: Broken configuration for this PCM:
> no configuration available

If we record directly from the loopback instance using *-d hw:10,0* it works fine. We're just unable to use the multi stream.

Comment: 16 channels per device ? Are you sure ?